# on hover replace image

Tags: html, css

How can I make the image change if the other image is

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <a href="klanten/detail/19/de-bibliotheek-zuid-kennemerland.html">
        <img src="cms_img/logo_zuidkennemerland7.png" alt="" />
        <img class="hover" src="cms_img/logo_zuidkennemerland72.png" alt="" />
     </a>       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

"hover" isn't a class.  It's a psuedo-class.  You need to create a div with the appropriate size and using CSS, give it one image as the background, and then the ":hover" class gives it the other image.

```
<style>

#mything {
 background-image: url(cms_img/logo_zuidkennemerland7.png);
}


#mything:hover {
 background-image: url(cms_img/logo_zuidkennemerland72.png);
}
</style>
```